# Programming language w/o pointers and sizeof?

Tags: programming, language

I'd like to create a source transpiler for a simple language to target high-level languages in general. For example, `AnyC++LikeLanguage` to Lua.

I'm looking for a language like C++¹, however...

- that doesn't depend on **bytes**;
- of preference, providing a built-in `string` class containing bytes, not ushorts;
- w/o **pointers**²;
- w/o **memory management**, <sub>only using internal gargabe collector</sub>;
- w/ **simple API**; e.g., no file system, no graphics, no garbage collector settings. Only console.

<sub>[1] like C++; I meant there'll be something like `import` or `# include` (possibly `require_once`), static-like namespaces, static-like structs, statically-typed variables, static types, multiple function signatures, function references (or "delegates"), maybe enumerations and some built-in types (`unsigned` (uint), `char` (byte), etc.).</sub>

<sub>[2] In LuaJ the unique way to implement pointers is using a table's array as a stack/heap. Each value would be allocated there, whose indices would be an address. However LuaJ may represent each value as a pointer, so it'll be more expensive yet.</sub>

So I'll be able to transpile it to LuaJ efficiently. Hope someone can suggest me an interesting one.

Comment: You don't define what is C++ like. Did you look into Scheme or Lisp (indeed their syntax is not C++ like)? Read also [*Programming Languages Pragmatics*](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch These languages look very beautiful. But I still would like some of the basic C++ features such as static typing, namespaces and maybe classes. I want nearly everything to be compile-time mostly, so it'll be more pleasant to output faster field accesses on LuaJ.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Clarified that "C++ like".

Comment: Did you look at Pascal? Maybe even Basic?